# Node js to wait till the response comes

Tags: node.js

```
copy_deliverable_script_tomaster(args.Software_name.value,function(state){
  res.end("added")
  }
)

function copy_deliverable_script_tomaster(software_name,callback){
  client.scp('./Temporary_software_files/folder/', {
  host: 'ip',
  username: 'centos',
  privateKey: String(require("fs").readFileSync('./foreman_keypairs/coe- 
  central.pem')),
  path: '/home/centos/Software_with_files/'+software_name
  }, function(err,response) {

  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  else{
    console.log("after copy in master")
    return callback(response);
}
})
}
```

I have used the above code, to copy large files to the remote machine.
Copying file continues in the remote machine, but the response("no content")comes before copy completes.
`console.log("after copy in master")`, will be printed only after the copy is completed.
Unable to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of res.end use `res.send("added");` or `res.write('Added'); res.end();`,

Because you have ended response without writing anything.

```
copy_deliverable_script_tomaster(args.Software_name.value, function (state) {
    res.send("added")
})
```

Comment: But i have used the same for all my API's, It is working fine. Only with respect to copying large file, i am not able to get response

Comment: Sure It's not getting the timeout? you need to handle error case also because, in case of error. the function is kept on waiting for the result. You need return callback.

Comment: Sorry rahul, if i am asking u very silly question. As i have understood,

Comment: else{
    console.log("after copy in master")
    return callback(response);
}

Comment: In err , i have given console.log. If err occurs , it will printed write

Comment: Can u please tell me, how to set the default timeout in node js for connect

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the error case. If you are not doing anything inside callback of `client.scp` then just pass the callback.

```
copy_deliverable_script_tomaster(args.Software_name.value, function (err,state) {
    if(err) return res.status(400).send(err);
    return res.send("some response")
})

function copy_deliverable_script_tomaster(software_name, callback) {
    client.scp('./Temporary_software_files/folder/', {
                host: 'ip',
                username: 'centos',
                privateKey: String(require("fs").readFileSync('./foreman_keypairs/coe-central.pem')),
                    path: '/home/centos/Software_with_files/' + software_name
                }, callback)
            }
```